# Facebook graph API does not return any metric from two days

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, analytics, social-media, facebook-analytics

I have been using graph API since june 2017 but from past two days its giving empty data for all metrics.
Does anyone know whats wrong with API??

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/pageid/insights?access_token=pageToken&pretty=1&since=1506495600&metric=**page_fans**&until=1506582000",
```

Answer (score 0):

finally the query got resolved and now the data is coming smoothly. 
Don't know how the read_insights permissions got removed for the app associated with my page. 
gave the read_insight permission again and the code is running very well now.

Comment: I faced the same problem! Can you explain me where I can find this permission?

Comment: you create an app associated with the page. you can find the get token tab.. click the down arrow and you ll get the list of options.. go for get user access token ,You will find  all the permissions required..  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/page_id/